# Get the entire line from a file which contains a number and string

Tags: string, bash, numbers, match

I have a variable set to a specific number, i.e. num=56 and a file full of numbers and other strings. I would like to match both the number and some of the string and get the entire line which contains them.

For example,

I want to match **this is my number: $num [mbits]** in a file full of similar lines such as the below.

```
random text in front - this is my number: 56 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 21 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 15 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 38 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 49 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 10 [mbits]  
random text in front - this is my number: 89 [mbits]
```

I am using the below command, but it does not work when I include the entire string.

**grep -n "this is my number: $num [mbits]" info.log >> info1.log**

The file remains empty.

It works only as **grep -n "this is my number:" info.log >> info1.log** and I get all the lines as above. I just need the one with the specific number.

The desired output should be,

**random text in front - this is my number: 56 [mbits]**

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `grep -F` (fixed string match):

```
num=56
grep -F "this is my number: $num [mbits]" info.log
```

Or else:

```
grep "this is my number: $num \[mbits\]" info.log
```

As `[` and `]` are special regex characters than need to be escaped.

**Output:**

```
random text in front - this is my number: 56 [mbits]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly, it somehow works, but I need to treat the $num as variable. Something goes wrong because of the double quotes...how do I print the variable value?